# call a method from different angular 2 app

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I am having two angular 2 apps in my website and I want to call a method from app 1 services in app 2 services, Note: the two apps are completely separated each of them has its own files and components
 [image]

Comment: You have to DI app1 into app2 and then you will be able to call app1 services from app2

Answer (score 2):

You can import the app1 module into app2

```
import { app1Module} from '../app1/app1.module';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [..., ...],
    imports:      [app1],
    bootstrap:    [...],
    providers: [...]
})
```

Or you can import the service class directly, so to import app1's service (app1Service) into app 2....

```
import { app1Service } from '../app1/services/app1.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [..., ...],
    imports:      [...],
    bootstrap:    [...],
    providers: [app1Service]
})
```

Comment: But for some reason I am still getting errors when I call method from app 1

Comment: You should edit your post and put up some code, it would be helpful to see both the modules for app1 and app2 as well as where you're trying to call the service method.